# How to express the powers of 10 with a first order sentence?

Tags: arithmetic, first-order-logic, natural-numbers

A subset $A \subseteq \mathbb N$ is called *arithmetical* if there exists a formula $\varphi$ in the language of first order arithmetic with exactly one free variable $x$ such that
$$x\in A \iff \varphi(x) = \texttt{true}$$

Here we take *first order arithmetic* to mean the language of well-formed sentences using only finitely many of the symbols $\forall$, $\exists$, $($, $)$, $x$, $y$, $z$ and other letters for variables, and the logical $\texttt{and}$, $\texttt{or}$, $\texttt{not}$, and $\implies$ operators, as well as the natural arithmetic symbols $0$, $1$, $+$, $\cdot$, and $=$. Variables range over the Peano naturals $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

Examples of arithmetical sets include

- Any finite or cofinite set, eg the singleton $\{5\}$ is expressed by the formula $\varphi(x) = (x = 5)$, where "$5$" is an abbreviation for $1+1+1+1+1$.
- The range of any polynomial with positive integer coefficients, eg the squares are expressed by the formula $\varphi(x) = \exists y(x = y \cdot y)$
- the primes, expressed by $\varphi(x) = (x > 1) \texttt{ and } \forall y(y | x \implies y = 1 \texttt{ or } y = x)$ where "$x|y$" is an abbreviation for $\exists z(y=x\cdot z)$
- for any prime $p$, the set of all powers of $p$, expressed by $\varphi(x) = \forall y(y|x \implies y = 1 \texttt{ or } p | y)$

**Question:**

> I am looking for a formula $\varphi$ that will witness the set of all powers of $10$, or any other composite integer.

It is easy to generalize the above example and capture the set $\{2^m 5^n : m,n \geq 0 \}$, but for the life of me I cannot get down to $\{2^n 5^n : n \geq 0\}$. I know one must exist because according to Wikipedia any *computable* set (a set for which there exists a finite computer program that will, on input $\texttt{n}$, output in finite time the $n$-th element of the set) is an arithmetical set, but I can't think of anything clever to characterize the powers of a composite integer.

---

More properties of arithmetical sets: if $A$, $B\subset \mathbb N$ are arithmetical, then so are

- $A\cup B$,
- $A\cap B$,
- $B\setminus A$,
- $A + B$,
- and $A \cdot B$.

There are only countably many arithmetical sets, and there are therefore uncountably many non-arithmetical sets. For any non-arithmetical set $X \subseteq \mathbb N$, one may find monotone sequences $(A_n)_n$ and $(B_n)_n$ of arithmetical sets such that

$$\bigcup_n A_n = X = \bigcap_n B_n$$

For instance, if $X = \{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ is an enumeration of $X$ and $Y = \{y_0,y_1,y_2,\ldots\}$ is an enumeration of $Y = X^c$ (because $X$ is not arithmetical then it is not finite or cofinite therefore both of these sets are infinite), then let $A_n = \{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and let $B_n = \mathbb N \setminus\{y_0, y_1,\ldots, y_n\}$.

Comment: See [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107960/write-a-statement-that-describes-the-powers-of-10)